# Failed To Compare/Decrypt Password (PHP/Android)

Tags: php, android, android-studio, encryption

I'm creating a basic log-in and register application on Android.

I'm currently facing a problem where I could encrypt the password (As seen on the image provide) but when I try to log-in in my Android application, it fails.

I tried to do an non-encrypted log-in and it works.

My theory is, the PHP file fails to compare or decrypt the password hash?

Code and screenshots below. Thank you for your time!

[Screenshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjq92.png)

[image]

**Login.php**

```
<?php
require("password.php");

$con = mysqli_connect("?", "?", "?", "?");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colUserID, $colName, $colUsername, $colAge, $colPassword);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    if (password_verify($password, $colPassword)) {
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $colName;
        $response["age"] = $colAge;
    }
}

echo json_encode($response); ?>
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
require("password.php");

$connect = mysqli_connect("?", "?", "?", "?");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

 function registerUser() {
    global $connect, $name, $age, $username, $password;
    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $passwordHash);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}

function usernameAvailable() {
    global $connect, $username;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 
    if ($count < 1){
        return true; 
    }else {
        return false; 
    }
}

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

if (usernameAvailable()){
    registerUser();
    $response["success"] = true;  
}

echo json_encode($response); ?>
```

**password.php**

```
<?php namespace {

if (!defined('PASSWORD_BCRYPT')) {
    /**
     * PHPUnit Process isolation caches constants, but not function declarations.
     * So we need to check if the constants are defined separately from 
     * the functions to enable supporting process isolation in userland
     * code.
     */
    define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT', 1);
    define('PASSWORD_DEFAULT', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST', 10);
}

if (!function_exists('password_hash')) {

    /**
     * Hash the password using the specified algorithm
     *
     * @param string $password The password to hash
     * @param int    $algo     The algorithm to use (Defined by PASSWORD_* constants)
     * @param array  $options  The options for the algorithm to use
     *
     * @return string|false The hashed password, or false on error.
     */
    function password_hash($password, $algo, array $options = array()) {
        if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
            trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_hash to function", E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }
        if (is_null($password) || is_int($password)) {
            $password = (string) $password;
        }
        if (!is_string($password)) {
            trigger_error("password_hash(): Password must be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }
        if (!is_int($algo)) {
            trigger_error("password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be long, " . gettype($algo) . " given", E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }
        $resultLength = 0;
        switch ($algo) {
            case PASSWORD_BCRYPT:
                $cost = PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST;
                if (isset($options['cost'])) {
                    $cost = (int) $options['cost'];
                    if ($cost < 4 || $cost > 31) {
                        trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Invalid bcrypt cost parameter specified: %d", $cost), E_USER_WARNING);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                // The length of salt to generate
                $raw_salt_len = 16;
                // The length required in the final serialization
                $required_salt_len = 22;
                $hash_format = sprintf("$2y$%02d$", $cost);
                // The expected length of the final crypt() output
                $resultLength = 60;
                break;
            default:
                trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Unknown password hashing algorithm: %s", $algo), E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
        }
        $salt_req_encoding = false;
        if (isset($options['salt'])) {
            switch (gettype($options['salt'])) {
                case 'NULL':
                case 'boolean':
                case 'integer':
                case 'double':
                case 'string':
                    $salt = (string) $options['salt'];
                    break;
                case 'object':
                    if (method_exists($options['salt'], '__tostring')) {
                        $salt = (string) $options['salt'];
                        break;
                    }
                case 'array':
                case 'resource':
                default:
                    trigger_error('password_hash(): Non-string salt parameter supplied', E_USER_WARNING);
                    return null;
            }
            if (PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($salt) < $required_salt_len) {
                trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: %d expecting %d", PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($salt), $required_salt_len), E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
            } elseif (0 == preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$#D', $salt)) {
                $salt_req_encoding = true;
            }
        } else {
            $buffer = '';
            $buffer_valid = false;
            if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv') && !defined('PHALANGER')) {
                $buffer = mcrypt_create_iv($raw_salt_len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
                if ($buffer) {
                    $buffer_valid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$buffer_valid && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
                $strong = false;
                $buffer = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($raw_salt_len, $strong);
                if ($buffer && $strong) {
                    $buffer_valid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$buffer_valid && @is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {
                $file = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
                $read = 0;
                $local_buffer = '';
                while ($read < $raw_salt_len) {
                    $local_buffer .= fread($file, $raw_salt_len - $read);
                    $read = PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($local_buffer);
                }
                fclose($file);
                if ($read >= $raw_salt_len) {
                    $buffer_valid = true;
                }
                $buffer = str_pad($buffer, $raw_salt_len, "\0") ^ str_pad($local_buffer, $raw_salt_len, "\0");
            }
            if (!$buffer_valid || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($buffer) < $raw_salt_len) {
                $buffer_length = PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($buffer);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $raw_salt_len; $i++) {
                    if ($i < $buffer_length) {
                        $buffer[$i] = $buffer[$i] ^ chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                    } else {
                        $buffer .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                    }
                }
            }
            $salt = $buffer;
            $salt_req_encoding = true;
        }
        if ($salt_req_encoding) {
            // encode string with the Base64 variant used by crypt
            $base64_digits =
                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
            $bcrypt64_digits =
                './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

            $base64_string = base64_encode($salt);
            $salt = strtr(rtrim($base64_string, '='), $base64_digits, $bcrypt64_digits);
        }
        $salt = PasswordCompat\binary\_substr($salt, 0, $required_salt_len);

        $hash = $hash_format . $salt;

        $ret = crypt($password, $hash);

        if (!is_string($ret) || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret) != $resultLength) {
            return false;
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * Get information about the password hash. Returns an array of the information
     * that was used to generate the password hash.
     *
     * array(
     *    'algo' => 1,
     *    'algoName' => 'bcrypt',
     *    'options' => array(
     *        'cost' => PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST,
     *    ),
     * )
     *
     * @param string $hash The password hash to extract info from
     *
     * @return array The array of information about the hash.
     */
    function password_get_info($hash) {
        $return = array(
            'algo' => 0,
            'algoName' => 'unknown',
            'options' => array(),
        );
        if (PasswordCompat\binary\_substr($hash, 0, 4) == '$2y$' && PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($hash) == 60) {
            $return['algo'] = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;
            $return['algoName'] = 'bcrypt';
            list($cost) = sscanf($hash, "$2y$%d$");
            $return['options']['cost'] = $cost;
        }
        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the password hash needs to be rehashed according to the options provided
     *
     * If the answer is true, after validating the password using password_verify, rehash it.
     *
     * @param string $hash    The hash to test
     * @param int    $algo    The algorithm used for new password hashes
     * @param array  $options The options array passed to password_hash
     *
     * @return boolean True if the password needs to be rehashed.
     */
    function password_needs_rehash($hash, $algo, array $options = array()) {
        $info = password_get_info($hash);
        if ($info['algo'] !== (int) $algo) {
            return true;
        }
        switch ($algo) {
            case PASSWORD_BCRYPT:
                $cost = isset($options['cost']) ? (int) $options['cost'] : PASSWORD_BCRYPT_DEFAULT_COST;
                if ($cost !== $info['options']['cost']) {
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Verify a password against a hash using a timing attack resistant approach
     *
     * @param string $password The password to verify
     * @param string $hash     The hash to verify against
     *
     * @return boolean If the password matches the hash
     */
    function password_verify($password, $hash) {
        if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
            trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_verify to function", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        $ret = crypt($password, $hash);
        if (!is_string($ret) || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret) != PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($hash) || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret) <= 13) {
            return false;
        }

        $status = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret); $i++) {
            $status |= (ord($ret[$i]) ^ ord($hash[$i]));
        }

        return $status === 0;
    }
} } namespace PasswordCompat\binary {

if (!function_exists('PasswordCompat\\binary\\_strlen')) {

    /**
     * Count the number of bytes in a string
     *
     * We cannot simply use strlen() for this, because it might be overwritten by the mbstring extension.
     * In this case, strlen() will count the number of *characters* based on the internal encoding. A
     * sequence of bytes might be regarded as a single multibyte character.
     *
     * @param string $binary_string The input string
     *
     * @internal
     * @return int The number of bytes
     */
    function _strlen($binary_string) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
            return mb_strlen($binary_string, '8bit');
        }
        return strlen($binary_string);
    }

    /**
     * Get a substring based on byte limits
     *
     * @see _strlen()
     *
     * @param string $binary_string The input string
     * @param int    $start
     * @param int    $length
     *
     * @internal
     * @return string The substring
     */
    function _substr($binary_string, $start, $length) {
        if (function_exists('mb_substr')) {
            return mb_substr($binary_string, $start, $length, '8bit');
        }
        return substr($binary_string, $start, $length);
    }

    /**
     * Check if current PHP version is compatible with the library
     *
     * @return boolean the check result
     */
    function check() {
        static $pass = NULL;

        if (is_null($pass)) {
            if (function_exists('crypt')) {
                $hash = '$2y$04$usesomesillystringfore7hnbRJHxXVLeakoG8K30oukPsA.ztMG';
                $test = crypt("password", $hash);
                $pass = $test == $hash;
            } else {
                $pass = false;
            }
        }
        return $pass;
    }

}}
```

Comment: Still looking for answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Blowfish is generally a better hashing algorithm and the following code is easier to implement (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

```
<?php

function password_hash($password, $cost=11){
        /* To generate the salt, first generate enough random bytes. Because
         * base64 returns one character for each 6 bits, the we should generate
         * at least 22*6/8=16.5 bytes, so we generate 17. Then we get the first
         * 22 base64 characters
         */
        $salt=substr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(17)),0,22);
        /* As blowfish takes a salt with the alphabet ./A-Za-z0-9 we have to
         * replace any '+' in the base64 string with '.'. We don't have to do
         * anything about the '=', as this only occurs when the b64 string is
         * padded, which is always after the first 22 characters.
         */
        $salt=str_replace("+",".",$salt);
        /* Next, create a string that will be passed to crypt, containing all
         * of the settings, separated by dollar signs
         */
        $param='$'.implode('$',array(
                "2y", //select the most secure version of blowfish (>=PHP 5.3.7)
                str_pad($cost,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT), //add the cost in two digits
                $salt //add the salt
        ));

        //now do the actual hashing
        return crypt($password,$param);
}

/*
* Check the password against a hash generated by the generate_hash
* function.
*/
function password_verify($password, $hash){
        /* Regenerating the with an available hash as the options parameter should
         * produce the same hash if the same password is passed.
         */
        return crypt($password, $hash)==$hash;
}
?>
```

Comment: Also, you are right that "the PHP file fails to decrypt the password hash" however i'm not sure exactly why, just that the above code worked better for me.

Comment: So, how do I properly implement the code? Should I just replace my password.php with this code? @Dan

Comment: Yes, just replace the entire password.php code with the Blowfish code and also I would recommend that you change this line in Register.php $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);                to change the PASSWORD_DEFAULT to rand() so it should read:    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, rand());   this gives the password_hash method a new random starting number to create the new hash with.

Comment: I tried replacing the password.php and replacing the $passwordHash but it doesn't register or even query when I submit the values. Went back to the same codes and it could encrypt the password but just couldn't log-in. Still maybe because it failed to compare the hash.

Comment: It worked for me... You might want to check that you have a.) the correct database connection details b.) the .php files have the correct permissions on your host to read and execute c.) in the first line of code require should be like: require '../public_html/password.php';   not using the () or "" but using single ' instead.

Comment: Hey, Dan. Thanks for the help, man! Unfortunately it still won't work. I tried your A, B & C suggestions. A.) I can confirm my database connection is correct B.) I tried Read-Write-Execute to all permissions C.) I tried changing my code for the require with the absolute URL in 000webhost but it seems it only accepts require ("");

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. 
Your original code is correct.

Just change the size of the password on your server to 255 chars (actually it should be 60 chars, recommended 255).

Answer (score 0):

you have to get hashed password first from your database and then compare it to your input password

Comment: Input password will comes plain string only right, then how will compare it. Provide the example codes here.